# Jenkins: Issue with running Windows Powershell script with AWS CLI commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, jenkins, aws-cli

all. I'm new in working with Jenkins and I will appreciate your help.

I have a 'build&publishLambda.ps1' powershell script to push zipped Lambda code to AWS S3 and update Lambda to use a new code version. In this script I use the following command to gain proper AWS Credentials for the session:

```
try {
    Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -ProfileName <Profile> -Region <Region>
    Write-Host "STEP 1: Authorization for accessing S3 was successfull." -ForegroundColor green `n
}
catch {
    Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor red `n 
    Write-Error "STEP 1: Authorization for accessing S3 failed." -ErrorAction:Stop
}
```

When I run this script locally - everything is OK.

Also I have a Jenkins build job with a step to call this powershell script ('Stop On Errors' and 'Use PowerShell profile' are enabled). I have the same AWS profile created on Jenkins server machine + when I run this script manually on Jenkins server everything is OK as well.

But when I call the script in a Jenkins build step as:

```
. "$ENV:WORKSPACE\build&publishLambda.ps1" -env dev
```

I receive the following error:

```
16:17:29 [Project] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins2516545345990457969.ps1
16:17:48 Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available. 
16:17:48 
16:17:48 C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Project\build&publishLamdba.ps1 : STEP 1: Authorization for accessing S3 failed.
16:17:48 At C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins2516545345990457969.ps1:2 char:1
16:17:48 + . "$ENV:WORKSPACE\build&publishLamdba.ps1" -env dev
16:17:48 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
16:17:48     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
16:17:48     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,build&publishLamdba.ps1
16:17:48  
16:17:48 Build step 'PowerShell' marked build as failure
```

Can you, please, clear out what I'm doing wrong, what is the reason for error and how this can be fixed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you need to assign an AWS Instance Role to the instance executing the Jenkins task (preferred way, but a bit complicated, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) or to include short-duration AWS credentials (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/) into the instance and making the temporary credentials public environment variables (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html: expose AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)

Comment: @AlexB, thank's for your help! That was it! Adding AWS roles solved my issue

Comment: Post it as an answer to your own question :) Good it helped. It's not easy stuff to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex B's first comment solved my issue. Here it is:

"Looks like you need to assign an AWS Instance Role to the instance executing the Jenkins task (preferred way, but a bit complicated, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) or to include short-duration AWS credentials (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/) into the instance and making the temporary credentials public environment variables (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html: expose AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)"